# Visual Studio 2010 not generating .pdb files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, debug-symbols

I was trying to debug a c++ app, but I saw breakpoints show "breakpoint will not be hit", so I checked the modules window and I saw "Binary was not build with debug information" so no symbols are loaded. And the only pdb file on the /debug folder is vc100.pdb, and there are no other pdb files anywhere in the project folders.

In properties C/C++ > Debug Information Format, I have set Program Database (/Zi). And runtime library is set to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

Am I missing any other setting that's causing not to create the pdb files?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You also need to have:
Properties > Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info = "Yes"