# No .pdb files generated when compiling openCV on VS2013

Tags: opencv, pdb-files

I cannot seem to locate the .pdb files after I have created the OpenCV binaries; using Cmake and then building the OpenCV solution using VS2013. Any help?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036017/visual-studio-2010-not-generating-pdb-files

Comment: The OpenCV.sln project properties has no Linker section in it

Comment: A `.sln` file *never* has any linker section. You need to check the `.vcxproj` file.

Comment: Thanks.
found the files after your suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Suggests in the comments above, see
[Visual Studio 2010 not generating .pdb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036017/visual-studio-2010-not-generating-pdb-files)

Plus different versions of OpenCV generate the files slightly differently. Search for .pdb files where you had compiled your OpenCV solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer for this specific question, but since I did not find the solution and question took about it, I write it to this thread. I hope it may be useful for other fellow sufferer.

My problem was that I could not reach a subset of code in Debugging. During the Debug mode it told, that "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document", [which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/fixing-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been-loaded-fo) is a well discussed problem. But the base problem was, that I could not even find a .pdb file, which should have been loaded, to reach that code. The problem was, that the Build properties of the project has not been set correctly.

To ensure, that you project generates the .pdb file, check the Build settings of the project:

Right click on project -> Select "Build" tab -> In the "Output" section click "Advanced..." button -> At "Debug Info:" dropdownlist select "full" option.