# Unable to attach to the process. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, devenv

I've been using the VS2015 Pre-RTM version for a bit which worked fine.
It was installed on an alternative drive to my system drive.

I have since uninstalled it and installed the RTM version in the default location (C:\Program Files (x86)\etc.). Since then I am unable to do anything debugging related. I always get the message in the title when I try to attach to any running process, or something similar when I try to debug any project, even when I change the launch command to something I know exists. Ctrl+f5 also works fine, it's really the debugging part that is broken.

I've tried many things in order to fix this, but nothing has worked so far.
I tried:

- Repairing the installation
- Reinstalling
- Run as admin
- Using /log and investigating the Activitylog.xml, which didn't feature anything useful
- Deleting all VS2015 related data in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
- Deleting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and 14.0_Config
- Tried analyzing with Procmon
- Diffing my procmon analysis with a working one, strangely enough some events with symbollocator.dll were missing from my run, but it seems to me that those events should be relevant from the moment after I successfully attached a debugger.
- Tried attaching a vs2012 debugger to vs2015 upon attaching a debugger, but nothing noteworthy came out of that.

I can't think of any more options to try and fix this problem, except for formatting my machine and reinstalling Visual Studio, but I really don't feel like doing that.

Is there any way to gather more verbose/debug output from visual studio? Or anything I can try in order to fix the issue?

It appears as if the debugger is broken somehow..

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it a C++ project? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036123/4136325

Comment: Anything, C++, C#, doesn't matter. I can't attach to anything, nor debug anything.

Comment: Finally! Found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34075693/1736785) and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't think that would have fixed it in my case, the fix seems to be really cordova specific, I had an issue with just attaching a debugger to anything. For instance to just step through the instructions in the disassembly window. But thanks for the contribution anyway :)

Comment: It's the same with VS 2017 for me. Any advice? APK is build, is pushed to the device, App is started - but debugging isn't working :/

Comment: Well, can you debug anything else with visual studio? Like a c# project? As this was a generic debugging issue regardless of debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after experimenting a bit further, I finally found a way in order to make the debugger work again.

In `Tools|Options|Debugging|General` if I enable:
`Use Managed Compatibility Mode` and `Use Native Compatibility Mode`, everything works again.

Though this is probably not the desired outcome and I'll investigate further:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: This made debugging work again for me, strange. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First go to Tool->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Run Dependency Checker to make sure you installed all the required components.

You might need to "Clear Cordova Cache"

Install Chrome extension for Apache Ripple. Restart your VS studio and try right clicking on your project and select DEPLOY, instead of Debug or F5.

Comment: There's no such thing under Tools > Options.

Answer (score 1):

On project properties->Debugging->Attach->No