# when trying to debug I get: Unable to Attach. The system could not find specified file

Tags: cordova

After doing the update 2 for visual studios 2015 tools for apache cordova, when trying to debug I get: Unable to Attach. The system could not find specified file. Does it on ripple and emulator.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled, ran repairs, but nothing works, It was good running the july RTM community version, but it would not just rollback to that.

I've read a couple other answers for 2013, but did not help or apply.

Also if you know where I can get the july 2015 release, I would go back and install that, but everything know is update 2?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have tried MANY of the "solutions" found and none have worked. Still looking for the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Installing TypeScript for VS 2015

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

solved the issue for me.